# Browser not opening when starting without debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Good morning all, I have a question that has come up with Visual Studio 2017 Community.  Each version of VS I've every had always opened a new browser window whenever you hit Ctrl+F5.  With VS 2017 Community though, I am finding it only fires up IIS.

Is there a setting to change to enable opening a new browser?  I'm semi-surprised it is not on by default.

So far, I have looked through the Options for the debugger but have yet to find a setting to turn on.  I am possibly overlooking it but it would be helpful to have some help in pointing out where to turn it on.

Comment: Maybe in the Settings -> Debug

Comment: I have looked through the settings.  Perhaps a bit more specific, like where and what...

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/

try make some test with settings untile someone know an already tested way

Comment: Interesting...  So, there is no real way to force it to launch IE when running without debugger.  That is an odd feature to drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a quick update and answer to this.  Recently, an update came out for Visual Studio 2017 Community edition and within this update was a fix for the issue mentioned (launching a browser when trying to run without debugger).